# Python Requests: downloaded image is corrupted

Tags: python, python-requests

I am saving image files from the web using Python Requests:

```
pic_url = bsObj.find('img', {"class":"image lazy-load"})['data-delayed-url']
response = requests.get(pic_url, stream=True)
with open(path + output['name'][0] + '.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
    response.raw.decode_content = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
```

However, the downloaded files seem all to be corrupted and cannot be opened. What could be the problem here?

**EDIT**

The code above works! It was a simple spelling mistake (thank you Pedro Lobito)

Comment: you may want to post more code, so we can get the full *picture*

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following code:

```
from io import BytesIO
with open(path + output['name'][0] + '.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(BytesIO(r.content), out_file)
```

Images are binary data. If you decode them as text, they will get corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

Check If **`pic_url` is correct**. Wouldn't it be simpler with `urllib`?

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(pic_url, path + output['name'][0] + '.jpg')
```